# Python BeautifulSoup and Pandas extract table from list of urls and save all the tables into single dataframe or save as csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract tabular data from a list of urls and I want to save all the table into a single csv file.

I am new and relatively beginner in python and from non-CS background, however I am very eager to learn the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

urls = ['A', 'B','C','D',...'Z']

for url in urls:
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='tbldata14 bdrtpg')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

data = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    data.append(row)

final_table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ABC", "XYZ",...])
final_table.to_csv (r'F:\Projects\McData.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

What I Get from above code in newly created csv file is  -

```
ABC XYZ PQR MNL CYP ZXS
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

My above code only gets table from **last url- 'Z'**, which, as I  have checked is actually the table from last url in list.

What I am trying to achieve here is getting all tables from list of urls - i.e. A to Z into single csv file.

Comment: thats because your `table_rows` is getting overwritten in first `for` each iteration - so it will have `last`url's rows only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with indentation and order. `table_rows` gets reset every time through the `for url in urls` loop, so you only end up with the last URLs worth of data.  If you want all of the URLs worth of data in one final CSV, see the changes I made below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

urls = ['A', 'B','C','D',...'Z']
data = [] # Moved to the start
for url in urls:
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='tbldata14 bdrtpg')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    #indented the following loop so it runs with every URL data
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in td]
        data.append(row)

final_table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ABC", "XYZ",...])
final_table.to_csv (r'F:\Projects\McData.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Comment: thanks the code is working properly now and I got my complete csv